# Java not detecting class?

Tags: java

So, I'm quite new to Java. I've learned quite a bit for being new. But...of course I don't understand everything.

I have 2 classes. One named "Random" and one name "ananas" (Ananas is French for Pineapple)

Random is my main class...but for some reason my main class (Random) is not detecting ananas.

Here is my script in ananas:

```
public class ananas {
    public String a(String PackageA){
        PackageA = "This file shall remain TOP SECRET! The ultimate universal secret code is...'Ananas'"; 
        return PackageA;
    }
    public String b(String PackageB){
        PackageB = "File not created yet";
        return PackageB;
    }
    public String c(String PackageC){
        PackageC = "File not created  yet";
        return PackageC;
    }

}
```

And here is my code in "Random":

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Random {
    public static void main(String ars[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, Please enter the code: "); 
        String hey = input.nextLine();
            if(hey .equals("The sandman ate my dollar"))

                System.out.println("Welcome! Please choose one: A), B), C)");
                    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String heyy = input2.nextLine();
                    if(heyy .equals("A)"))
                        System.out.println("File  not created yet");

                    else if(heyy .equals("B)"))
                        System.out.println("Flid not created yet");

                    else if(heyy .equals("C)"))
                        System.out.println("File not created yet");
                    else 
                        System.out.println("Access Denied");
```

I tried to do: "ananas abc = new ananas();"

But even when I go to run my code, it only detects "Random"

Please help?

Comment: Please note that classes in java should start with capitalized letter

Comment: Your classes should start with a capitol letter (ananas -> Ananas),
and your variables with a lower case letter (PackageA --> packageA).
Your code would still run, but this is common practice.

Comment: I have no Idea what you mean by "it detects". Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the code you have in Random, you are never constructing an instance of ananas.
As your methods in Ananas are not static, you need to create an instance of the class.

```
Ananas a = new Ananas(); // Construct new instance calling the default constructor

// Note that you have named your methods so that nobody can really understand what they do!
// Now, to call methods from this class, you would do it like this
//First a = the instance of ananas class we just built. The second a is the method in the class we wish to call. String is the parameter the method requires.
a.a(string);
```

As it looks you want to invoke the method from the class Ananas depending upon the input the user gives, you could modify your code to do it like this.

```
if(heyy.equals("A)"){
      a.a(yourString); // You need to create the ananas instance before this, and have a string called yourString that you pass on to the method
}
```

A better solution in this case would be, to not require the methods in ananas to require String parameter. Also consider naming the method so it describes what it is doing! The change required would be as simple as this:

```
public String a(){ // a could be something like 'getStringA'
        String PackageA = "This file shall remain TOP SECRET! The ultimate universal secret code is...'Ananas'"; 
        return PackageA;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no constructor in ananas.

It should have something like:

```
public ananas(){
System.out.println("I like pineapples");
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: If you don't create a constructor Java will automatically make an empty one for you, so this isn't needed.